# Qt and opencv4android

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, android

This is y first post, I've been working with Qt and opencv and I'm new in opencv4android, I want to make a Qt application for android that uses opencv,but I don't know how to do this.

I saw this post: http://amin-ahmadi.com/2015/06/23/opencv-qt-android-adding-required-libraries-and-includes/  and tried to include the paths to the libs but when I compile I get errors like this because I'm using opencv2:

**opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include**

I don't know if the opencv4android functions are different than the normal opencv ones, what am I missing to get my project compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add OpenCV to your INCLUDEPATH in your *.pro file.

```
OPENCVSDKNATIVE = $$PWD/3rdparty/opencv-android-sdk/sdk/native # replace with your OpenCV SDK for Android location
INCLUDEPATH += $$OPENCVSDKNATIVE/jni/include
```